# MSSQL Sum by EntryDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called "Data". With columns: "Number" and "EntryDate".
The EntryDate is Datetime( Y-m-d h:i:s ).

I need to calculate the sum of all entries from a date ignore h:i:s, group them by the date.

Example:

```
Number | EntryDate
-------------------
23     | 2018-10-01 13:22:10.520
25     | 2018-10-01 11:16:09.533
```

So basically I need to SUM the Number from 2018-10-01.
I have tried several variations but nothing seems to work, for example:

```
SELECT
SUM(Number) as 'Sum',
EntryDate AS DATE
FROM Data
GROUP BY EntryDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date is at the moment in the datetime format, hence if you select date within your select query, you wont really get the date, instead you would get the respective datetimes.

What you can do is **Convert** the EntryDate as date:

Try:

select sum(number) as 'Sum', convert(date,EntryDate) as 'Date'
from Data
group by convert(date,EntryDate)

Should work. 
Go seek more information from here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Use cast() function for converting datetime to date

```
SELECT
SUM(Number) as 'Sum', cast(EntryDate as date) AS `DATE`
FROM Data
GROUP BY cast(EntryDate as date
```

Comment: DATE() function doesn't work because this is MSSQL ( or at least the version it's being used). So it says that Date is not a built-in function